# Saving a position with Lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to use xml-conduit and xml-lens for parsing and traversing an XML document. Instead of having to traverse the same parts of the document multiple times, I would like to store the traversal up until the previous point and then drill down further.

ex.

```
let pos = doc ^. root . el "foo"
    bar = pos . text
    baz = pos ./ el "quux" . text
```

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
No instance for (Data.Monoid.Monoid Element)
  arising from a use of `el'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Data.Monoid.Monoid Element)
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `el "foo"'
In the second argument of `(^.)', namely `root . el "foo"'
In the expression: doc ^. root . el "foo"
```

What can I do to store this intermediate position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type error happens because `el` is a `Traversal`. Traversals point to multiple values (in this case, all `foo` elements). `(^.)`, on the other hand, always returns a single value. Using `(^.)` with a `Traversal` only works if the target type is a `Monoid`; in that case, the multiple values are smashed into a single one using `mappend`. `Element`, however, is not a `Monoid` (because there is no sensible way to combine XML elements into a single element), and so `(^.)` does not work. To get the matched XML elements, you should use [`(^..)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v%3a-94-..) instead, which will return them as a list.

As for the question proper ("What can I do to store this intermediate position?"), the `Traversal` is a reference to the position, so if you want to compose it further you don't want to "dereference" it with `(^.)` or `(^..)`. The following should work:

```
let pos = root . el "foo"
    baz = pos ./ el "quux" . text
    elemTexts = doc ^.. baz
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the error. If I need to use the same position multiple times though, won't it still need to traverse the document each time since I'm basically just saving how to traverse to that position but not actually doing it.

Comment: @Adam Yes if you reuse `pos` and `baz`. If you are worried about that you can drop the `text` traversal from `baz` and reuse `elms = doc ^.. baz`, which will then be the (already dereferenced) list of elements.

Comment: If I use `(^..)` to get a list of the elements, can the list then be turned back into a `Traversal'` so I can use the other functions in xml-lens on it afterwards?

Comment: @Adam You can write a separate traversal to carry on from where you stopped. It might look like `traverse ./ el "glub"` (`traverse` is the vanilla traversal, which goes through everything there is to traverse), and you can use it with `(^..)` (e.g. `elms ^.. traverse ./ el "glub"`).